# React Native Android Component is not being invoked

Tags: javascript, android, nfc, react-native

I have made a custom react native module to get NFC Card ID and send it (SendEvent) to React Native.

I'm listening on React Native ( Device Event Emitter, Listener ), But the module never get invoked when NFC is attached.

```js
componentDidMount(){
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('nfc', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

I've registered the app to be opened when nfc tag is discovered (through Manifest), so when you attach a nfc tag, app will be opened, but the custom modules doesn't run, or not being invoked.

Should i set it in manifest to be invoked when nfc is found? (Intent?)
NfcReactNativeModule.java

```js
class NfcReactNativeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public NfcReactNativeModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        this.reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        MifareClassic tag = MifareClassic.get( (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
  
  tag.connect();
  
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(tag.getTag().getId());
  int id = bb.getInt();
  
  WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
  params.putInt("id", id);
  
  sendEvent(reactContext, "nfc", params);
  
  tag.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(
      final Activity activity,
      final int requestCode,
      final int resultCode,
      final Intent intent) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "NfcReactNative";
    }
 
 private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
  reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName, params);
 }
    
}
```

NfcReactNativePackage.java

```js
public class NfcReactNativePackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new NfcReactNativeModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest for react native android project :

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="XXXXXXX"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="2.1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/XXXXXXX"
      android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="XXXXXXX" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>

          <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
              android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

      <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Android react native project :
android/app/src/main/res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml :

```js
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcBarcode</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```